# Nested Array Troubleshoot for Perl

Tags: perl, multidimensional-array

I am having trouble with my array of references which point to another array. Here's a snippet of my code:

```
# @bah is a local variable array that's been populated, @foo is also initialized as a global variable
$foo[9] = \@bah; 

# this works perfectly, printing the first element of the array @bah
print $foo[9][0]."\n"; 

# this does not work, nothing gets printed
foreach (@$foo[9]) {
    print $_."\n";
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Always `use strict;` and `use warnings;`.

The `@` dereference takes precedence, so `@$foo[9]` expects `$foo` to be an array reference and gets element 9 from that array.  You want `@{$foo[9]}`.  `use strict` would have alerted you that `$foo` was being used, not `@foo`.

For some easily memorizable rules for dereferencing, see http://perlmonks.org/?node=References+quick+reference.

Answer (score 1):

Like ysth says, you need to use braces to properly dereference `$foo[9]` into the array it points to.

You may however also want to be aware that using `\@bah` you are directly referencing the array. So that if change `@bah` later on, you will change `$foo[9]` as well:

```
my @bah = (1,2,3);
$foo[9] = \@bah;
@bah = ('a','b','c');
print qq(@{$foo[9]});
```

This will print `a b c`, and not `1 2 3`.

To only copy the values from `@bah`, instead dereference `$foo`:

```
@{$foo[9]} = @bah;
```